# expire all the new and manually reset passwords

Tags: linux, password, accounts

I need to expire all the new and manually reset passwords in a server. When a new user logs into the server the first time it should force him to change the password. My first guess is that I have to use the command chage -d 0

Answer (score 2):

After creating user you may use

```
[root@localhost~]# chage -d 0 username
```

to force a user to change their password at next logon on a Linux.

If you want to automatically do that every time just after new user add. For that you edit the configuration file which locate at

```
[root@localhost] # vi /etc/default/useradd
```

Search  Expire and Make it

```
Expire=0
```